# Create NVD3 Semicircle Donut using rCharts

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts, donut-chart

I am trying to create a simple semicircle donut using `rCharts` and the `NVD3` javascript library. A minimum reproducible example of a full donut is provided below.

```
library(rCharts)
data1 <- data.frame(label=c("A","B","C"), value=c("1000","2000","3000"))
n1 <- nPlot(value~label, data = data1, type = "pieChart")
n1$chart(donut=TRUE)
n1
```

My problem arises when I try to specify the `startAngle` and `endAngle` options as provided [here](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#pieChart) in the NVD3 documentation, in order to convert this donut into a semicircle donut.

```
# This gives me a blank Viewer pane
n1$chart(donut=TRUE,
         startAngle="#!function(d){return d.startAngle/2-Math.PI/2;}!#",
         endAngle="#!function(d){return d.endAngle/2-Math.PI/2;}!#")
n1
```

Looking at code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222038/donut-pie-chart-add-a-title-nvd3-js) question, it appears that passing `startAngle` and `endAngle` to the `n1$params$chart` may not be the right way to do this, although that is what I would expect based on the fact that `donut=TRUE` works.

It is also possible that one of my callback functions has improper syntax - in my experience, this sort of problem can crash entire visualizations. However, I am fairly certain that I have used exactly the same callback function provided in the NVD3 documentation.

Comment: Note: trying to add the `growOnHover` option to `n1$charts` also breaks the visualization in a similar manner.

Comment: Try HighCharts instead !

Comment: Just tried that yesterday and had it up and running in 5 minutes using highcharts!

Answer (score 1):

The rCharts library does not allow you to do this as is. I forked it and modified it to include the latest nvd3 JavaScript and added the possibility to add parameters to chart.pie via the .$pie function in R.

You can grab the rCharts fork here: https://github.com/clecocel/rCharts

For a minimum example based on rCharts' quickstart:

```
p5 <- nPlot(~ cyl, data = mtcars, type = 'pieChart')
p5
```

You'll see that the `growOnHover` option is now activated by default.

To create a half donut you can now indeed use:

```
p5$chart(donut=T)
p5$pie(startAngle="#!function(d){return d.startAngle/2-Math.PI/2;}!#",
       endAngle="#!function(d){return d.endAngle/2-Math.PI/2;}!#"))
```